# jQuery UI Datepicker won't accept unix timestamp as default value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the Unix timestamp "1264529457", which translates into January 26, 2010, which is stored inside an input element named "america".

When initializing jQuery UI's Datepicker, I have the following code to set the default date:

```
defaultDate: $.datepicker.parseDate('@', $("input[name=america]").val()),
```

When I manually check to see what this comes out to in Firebug, it says "Thu Jan 15 1970 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) {}". Any idea what is wrong (the documentation for this function is a bit sparse, so I'm guessing I missed something)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unix time is stored in seconds while Javascript uses milliseconds.  Try multiplying your Unix timestamp by 1000 first.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ben is correct, you need to multiply the timestamp by 1000 as Javascript uses miliseconds.
This should work.

`defaultDate: $.datepicker.parseDate('@', $("input[name=america]").val()*1000),`

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass that value to the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date) constructor as a number, like this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(parseInt($("input[name=america]").val(), 10))
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/d4CEf/).

Comment: Prefer the solution below, but I'll keep that in mind too. That link you posted looks really useful --- I'll have to mess around with that later.